# Audience Network new placement cannot be set to rewarded video

Tags: facebook, admob, facebook-audience-network, rewardedvideoad

I am currently trying to set Facebook's Audience Network rewarded video as a mediation group in AdMob. In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/mediation/facebook) for this there is a step that I simply can't complete:

"**Select Rewarded Video as the Display Format**. Set your price setting. Double-check that the Status dropdown at the top of the form is set to Enabled, then click Save to create your placement."
As you can see, I don't even have that option...

[image: No Rewarded Video option in Display Format]

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help :)

Comment: Were you able to integrate rewarded ads?